# How do I stretch a GridLayout to its parent?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to stretch the keyboard of my calculator (which is a GridLayout with buttons inside of it). It is a 5*4(columns*rows).

1. I give `GridLayout` `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to make its dimensions fill the available space. then
2. I assign the column and row indices to the cells with `android:layout_column` an `android:layout_row` accordingly.

I get the following result:

**1080x1920**

[image]

The cells take an uniform width and height, but do not stretch enough to fill the whole grid. So I searched online and saw that I could assign an equal weight to each cell and the layout figures out a uniform width and height value that fills the whole grid.

(Side question: how does android determine the size of these cells in this case? why did it not make them larger/smaller than what it is here?)

So I add:

1. `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="1"` to each of the buttons

I get this result:

**1080x1920**

[image]

Awesome. Looks like it is working as intended.. until I change the resolution to something else:

**480x800**

[image]

Or if I keep the same **1080x1920** resolution but force the min height of the top section to something like `280dp` (279dp works fine)

[image]

How can I fix this? I am intending API Level 21 and I want to force the GridLayout to fill the available space no matter. I prefer the buttons to be squeezed (even have their content clipped/ invisible) rather than to shoot off the screen. To finish here is the XML:

## main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root">
<!--Top section (screen + few keys)-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:style="@style/CalculatorScreenStyle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="280dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:hint="Enter a number here"/>
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- Keyboard layout -->
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5">
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="C"
            android:id="@+id/clearButton"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:id="@+id/percentButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/divideButton"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="÷" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:id="@+id/sevenNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:id="@+id/eightNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:id="@+id/nineNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:id="@+id/plusButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:id="@+id/fourNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:id="@+id/fiveNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:id="@+id/sixNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="x"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:id="@+id/multiplyButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:id="@+id/oneNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:id="@+id/twoNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:id="@+id/threeNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:id="@+id/minusButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="+/-"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:id="@+id/signButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:id="@+id/zeroNumButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="."
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:id="@+id/periodButton" />
        <Button
            android:style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
            android:text="="
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:id="@+id/equalsButton" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

## styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CalculatorButtonStyle" >
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:background">#9E5EC2</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CalculatorScreenStyle">
    <item name="android:background">#ED59E8</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

EDIT: As a temporary solution, I am using a vertical `LinearLayout` of horizontals `LinearLayout`s and I assing an equal weights to all the `Button`s. It works fine but then I wonder what is the use of `GridLayout` if I have to emulate how it works myself..

[image]

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When android API level < 21, it doesn't work well.

So we can add dependency in app gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
```

**If you've still not migrated to androidx (which you ought to), then use:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

Then change your code.

Use androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout (or `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`, if not androidx) in your XML code.

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:rowCount="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="C"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/percentButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="%"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divideButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="÷"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sevenNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eightNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="8"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nineNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="9"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plusButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fourNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fiveNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sixNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="6"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multiplyButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="x"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/oneNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twoNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/threeNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minusButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="-"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="+/-"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zeroNumButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/periodButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="."
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/equalsButton"
        style="@style/CalculatorButtonStyle"
        android:text="="
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
</androidx.gridlayout.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

**Note**

The new attributes are:

- app:layout_columnWeight
- app:layout_rowWeight
- app:layout_rowSpan
- app:layout_columnSpan